# how far we come with a near to perfect frictionless surface?

Tags: friction

In today's world, friction is present everywhere, but I am curious about that how far we come with a near to perfect frictionless surface?

Comment: Will you only accept bodies in direct contact, or would you also accept answers with a lubricant?  Also, what about skates on ice, where a thin layer of water is created from the contact pressure?  How about cases where a layer of air is injected, such as on an air hockey table?

Comment: Interplanetary space probes don't see much friction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a "superteflon" frying pan, then we still have some way to go, although the latest replacement hip joint surfaces are pretty smooth

We already have achieved an, in effect, frictionless surface, if you accept that it's not something you come across on an everyday basis.

Also, you could argue that it's not only the surface that's frictionless, but the "moving" element, to which I would reply that as no friction is encountered, then it's effectively an answer to your question.

From [Supersolid Helium](https://m.phys.org/news/2007-02-high-quality-helium-crystals-supersolid-behavior.html)

> The researchers relied on inertia to determine that the ultra-cold solid helium had a supersolid component. They did the high-pressure cooling experiment in a tiny torsional oscillator, a pendulum-like setup. Liquid helium, under pressure, entered a small chamber at the end of a thin rod. The liquid then cooled to the solid phase and the torsional oscillator was set at a specific frequency.
>
> With a normal solid, the total mass of the sample would dictate the force required to move the oscillator at a specific frequency and as long as the mass remained the same, the same force would be required to keep the system at the same frequency . In Chan and Kim's experiment, when the temperature went below 0.2 degrees Kelvin, the frequency abruptly increased, indicating that some of the solid helium was not moving with the chamber or with the rest of the solid. "At about 25 atmospheres, the initial pressure we investigated, 1 percent of the helium becomes a supersolid," says Chan. "This supersolid fraction becomes frictionless, allowing the rest of the helium to 'flow' past it."